# Getting environment variables to work in next js and netlify

Tags: javascript, deployment, environment-variables, next.js, netlify

I have deployed a next js application to netlify using git and I have a `.env.local` file that stores the backend route url that I use everywhere throughout the app when making fetch requests. The problem is that after deployment the process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_ROUTE returns undefined.

The `.env.local` file:

`NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_ROUTE=https://[the name of the url].herokuapp.com/`

An example of a page using the environment varible:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_ROUTE}/findAllPictures`)
      .then((doc) => {
        const arr = doc.data;

        if (arr.length !== 0) {
          const mappedArr = arr.map((obj) => {
            return obj.id;
          });
          const amount = mappedArr.length;
          const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * amount);
          const routeId = mappedArr[rand];
          router.push(`/view/${routeId}`);
        }
      });
  }, [null]);
  return <div></div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities I see

1. your `.env.local` file  is not in root
2. Some weird formatting issue is going on with the variables. In that case, try surrounding your variable in quotes:

   NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_ROUTE="https://[the name of the url].herokuapp.com/"

Comment: The .env.local file got added to .gitignore automatically after bootstrapping the app, ty for the help.